# Is there a way to have methods run on multiple threads using RxJava

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

I'm new to RxJava and I'm trying to figure out if there is an equivalent to running multiple async tasks on various threads in parallel.

I understand the RxJava equivalent of

```
AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, ObjectType>(){
    @Override
    protected ObjectType doInBackground(String... params) {
         return someMethod(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ObjectType objectType) {}
}

aynctask.execute();
```

is

```
Observable.just(string)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map(this::someMethod)
    .subscribe(new Observer<ObjectType>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {}

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {}

        @Override
        public void onNext(ObjectType objectType) {}
    });
```

But how can I implement in RxJava the equivalent of

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is answered very well by the "Scheduler" section of the Rx Java documentation, located [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Scheduler). I will not attempt to summarise that wealth of information here suffice to say that the equivalent of `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` is to get the operators in your cascade of Observable operators to operate on particular schedulers.

In particular, you can use the [Schedulers.from(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html#from(java.util.concurrent.Executor)) method to execute the operator on a particular `java.util.concurrent.Executor`.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning, that default computation scheduler uses ThreadPool internally.